# получить getSharedPreferences из Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-shared-preferences

в активити есть TabLayout с ViewPager'ом, в который адаптер должен загружать 2 страницы xml

**user_favs.java**

```
userFavsAdapter favsAdapter=new userFavsAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
user_favs_viewpager.setAdapter(favsAdapter);
user_favs_tablayout.setupWithViewPager(user_favs_viewpager);
```

**userFavsAdapter.java extends FragmentPagerAdapter**

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0)
        return new user_fav_stores();
    else
        return new user_fav_items();
}
```

В SharedPreferences уже сохранена некоторая инфа. Ее нужно получить из фрагментов

**user_fav_stores.java extends Fragment**

```
String user_id="";
String user_stores="";

public user_fav_stores(){
    SharedPreferences logininfo=getContext().getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO,MODE_PRIVATE);
    /* или другие варианты */
    SharedPreferences logininfo=this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences logininfo=getContext().getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO,MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences logininfo=getContext().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Values.APP_LOGIN_INFO,MODE_PRIVATE); 
    /*   */
    if(logininfo!=null){
        if(logininfo.getString("auth_type","").equals("user")) {
            user_id=logininfo.getString("userid","");
            user_stores=logininfo.getString("stores","");
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fav_stores, container, false);
    lv=(ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.user_fav_stores);

    (new getUserStores()).execute();
    return root;
}
```

**user_fav_items.java** аналогично

Все варианты получить SharedPreferences дают

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
```

как же их получить?

Comment: используйте `getActivity()`

Comment: @rjhdby, это не поможет) ТС пытается в конструкторе получить контекст)

Comment: @rjhdby, метод `public user_fav_stores()` в последнем блоке кода. Из-за несоблюдения ТС-ом правил именования код плохо читается, да)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а, блин, понял где здесь конструктор. Правильное именование - половина успеха :D

Comment: @rjhdby ага))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Именовать в `Java` надо `camelCase`-ом, иначе ваш код становится нечитаемым. Имена классов должны быть с большой буквы.
2. Конструкторы активити и фрагментов использовать нельзя. Это системные компоненты и система сама создаёт их экземпляры. Вы должны использовать только методы жизненного цикла этих компонентов.
3. Получить контекст можно методом фрагмента `getActivity()`. Но только после того, как фрагмент будет добавлен в активити. Это произойдёт только после вызова `onAttach(Context context)` метода фрагмента (вызов будет сделан системой после выполнения асинхронной операции добавления фрагмента)

Т.е. вы можете перенести код из конструктора фрагмента в метод `onCreateView` и тогда всё должно заработать.

И обязательно надо переименовать все классы и переменные чтобы код стал читаемым для джавистов.